# How to remove characters from string and make result a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of span elements that contain urls, however they have unwanted characters at the start and end of the string.

```
<span class="value"> : 'http://www.barratthomes.co.uk/new-homes/cambridgeshire/H618701-Trumpington-Meadows/'</span>

<span class="value"> : 'http://www.barratthomes.co.uk/new-homes/cambridgeshire/H618701-Trumpington-Meadows/'</span>

<span class="value"> : 'http://www.barratthomes.co.uk/new-homes/cambridgeshire/H618701-Trumpington-Meadows/'</span>

<span class="value"> : 'http://www.barratthomes.co.uk/new-homes/cambridgeshire/H618701-Trumpington-Meadows/'</span>
```

There is the space colon another space and quote at the beginning and a quote at the end

These corrected values need to be put within `<a>` tags that stay within the `span` tags and have the url as the `href` and the link name.

I.e.

```
<span class="value"><a href="http://www.barratthomes.co.uk/new-homes/cambridgeshire/H618701-Trumpington-Meadows/">http://www.barratthomes.co.uk/new-homes/cambridgeshire/H618701-Trumpington-Meadows/</a></span>
```

This is what I have so far

```
$('span.value').each(function () {
   $('.value').text().substr(4, this.length-2);
});


$('span.value').each(function () {
    $('span.value').wrapInner(function () {
        return "<a href='" + $('span.value').nodeValue + "'></a>";
    });
});
```

I'm not sure how to combine them into one function

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Generally, that question would be about some code you've written in an attempt to solve the problem. Oh, and you also forgot to include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it without regex.

```
   $('.value').each(function(){
      var res = $(this).text().split("").filter(function(index){
          return index != "'" && index != ":" && index != " ";
      });
      console.log(res.join(""));
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zrwa7fm/)

**EDIT:**

```
$('.value').each(function(){
      var res = $(this).text().split("").filter(function(index){
          return index != "'" && index != " ";
      }).slice(1);
      console.log(res.join(""));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great apart from it removes the `:` after the `http` in the url.

Comment: @Pedroson ah yes. If you want me to fix it let me know.

Comment: Yes please that would be great if you could

Comment: @Pedroson check update

Comment: Perfect thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript's replace method with regex.

```js
var string = "<span class=\"value\"> : 'http://www.barratthomes.co.uk/new-homes/cambridgeshire/H618701-Trumpington-Meadows/'</span>";

var new_string = string.replace(/(.*?) : '(.*?)'/i, "$1<a href='$2'>$2</a>");
                                
alert(new_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how to combine them into one function

You are already selecting the elements you want to operate on, then iterating through that set using `.each()`.  In your callback, `this` will be the current element for that step of the iteration.  So wrap it in a jQuery object and use it.

```
$('span.value').each(function () {
   var target = $(this).text().substr(4, this.length-2);
   $(this).wrapInner(function () {
        return "<a href='" + target + "'></a>";
    });
});
```